# .url is using the secure protocol even when no protocol is added in the latest chromedriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

It seems that the url function is using the secure protocol even when specifically doesn't have it. This worked fine until latest chrome-driver update Versión 120.0.6099.71 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

.url("http://test.test.test")
is navigating to https://test.test.test with the latest chrome-driver.

Any advice is welcome

I believe this is an injection.
Regards,